# "while" loop in windows forms apllication - no window is opened (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, while-loop, phantomjs

I am new to C# and I want to create a windows forms application, which shows (it must be visible!) one window with some information and buttons and also it loads a page from internet (with selenium and phantom.js - though it is deprecated) every minute. I've written something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Someclass : Form
    {
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Someclass_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Shows some text "Hello friend" 
            MessageBox.Show("Hello friend!");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello again", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        public Someclass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
       
            while (!IsDisposed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Now the page will be downloaded");
                var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; 
                using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
                {
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
                    MessageBox.Show("Here we are going to open StackOverflow");
                    var questions = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("fs-display2"));
                    foreach (var question in questions)
                    {
                        // This will display some text from stackoverflow main page.
                        Console.WriteLine(question.Text);
                        question.Click();
                        MessageBox.Show("This is stackoverflow: " + question.Text);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Here we go");
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000); // delay in microseconds
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I use "while", my window does not appear (but the page from internet loads correctly - every 1 minute), and if I use "if" instead of "while", my window appears well, but, of cource, the page loading goes only one time. What can solve my problem?

Comment: That code cannot be placed there. When the constructor is called the form still doesn't exist. InitializeCompoment will start creating the object included in your form but the loop will never allow the forms engine to complete the work to put your form on screen. That code could be inserted as an event handler for some click event on a button. Or placed in a BackgroundWorker DoWork event or as an event handler for a Timer object.

Comment: you are most likely blocking the thread that wants to show your window by constantly doing that work on the UI thread. The reason it works with the If is that once you've done your downloading it can then go back to drawing your UI. The While loop occupies the UI thread and never gives it back to draw stuff

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite simple solution: your while loop is preventing your UI from Update. You have to bring your loop in an extra Thread, or just use a backgroundworker

Comment: It's doing more than that, it's not even letting the constructor run

Comment: well, it's exactly doing that! preventing the constructor, which is running in the UI thread from finishing, nothing more! The OP has to understand the reason, than he will understand the consequence ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, friends, you were right. I have put (using panel of instruments-> Background Worker):

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
 while (!IsDisposed)
{
......................
}
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000); // delay in microseconds
}
```

inside my **public partial class someClass : Form** after *public Someclass()*

and also added:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
```

inside my **public Someclass()**

So now the code looks like:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
    
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Someclass : Form
        {
            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }
    
            private void Someclass_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }
     
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Shows some text "Hello friend" 
                MessageBox.Show("Hello friend!");
            }
    
            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello again", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
    
            public Someclass()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
            }
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
    this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
     while (!IsDisposed)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Now the page will be downloaded");
                var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; 
                using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
                {
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
                    MessageBox.Show("Here we are going to open StackOverflow");
                    var questions = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("fs-display2"));
                    foreach (var question in questions)
                    {
                        // This will display some text from stackoverflow main page.
                        Console.WriteLine(question.Text);
                        question.Click();
                        MessageBox.Show("This is stackoverflow: " + question.Text);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Here we go");
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000); // delay in microseconds
    }
        }
    }
```

and works fine.